# Not able to run my sample spring boot app

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I followed the following article and setup the project

https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-rest-api-tutorial-with-mysql-jpa-hibernate/

I am attaching the POM for reference.
when I run the project I get :

> 2019-12-11 14:53:12.373  WARN 10004 --- [  restartedMain]
>   ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered
>   during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'noteController': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'noteRepository'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'com.example.easynotes.repository.NoteRepository' available: expected
>   at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency
>   annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>   2019-12-11 14:53:12.389  INFO 10004 --- [  restartedMain]
>   o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
>   2019-12-11 14:53:12.389  INFO 10004 --- [  restartedMain]
>   ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :
>
> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report
>   re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2019-12-11 14:53:12.499
>   ERROR 10004 --- [  restartedMain]
>   o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :
>
> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Field noteRepository in
>   com.example.easynotes.controller.NoteController required a bean of
>   type 'com.example.easynotes.repository.NoteRepository' that could not
>   be found.
>
> The injection point has the following annotations:
>           - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
>   'com.example.easynotes.repository.NoteRepository' in your
>   configuration.

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>easy-notes</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>easy-notes</name>
    <description>Rest API for a Simple Note Taking Application</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>

            <scope>runtime</scope>
                    <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

---

NoteRepository Interface:

```
package com.example.easynotes.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import com.example.easynotes.model.Note;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface NoteRepository extends JpaRepository<Note,Long> {

}
```

Comment: paste your `noteRepository`

Comment: Your dependencies are a mess. Remove the `org.hibernate.javax.persistence`, `spring-data-jpa`, `spring-boot-dependencies` and `spring-aspects` dependencies and add a `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency. Also make sure that your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class is in the `com.example.easynotes` package.

Comment: I cleaned up the pom and ran the app again and it worked. Thanks Deinum. I can put the latest pom and mark your answer

Answer (score -1):

1. Mark Your `NoteRepository` class with `@Repository` annotation.
2. And mark your main class with `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.example.easynotes.repository"})`

Comment: spring will scan automatically, their's no need to add `@EnableJpaRepositories` unless you are tempering with basic structure from spring boot guidelines

Comment: Depends if you are using @ComponentScan or not. If You're not using the current package for everything.

Comment: @SagarAhuja If you're using `SpringBootApplication` annotation at the top level class then no need of explicitly adding `ComponentScan` annotation in Spring Boot Project.

Comment: What I am trying to say is that my base class is under `src/main/java/com/base` package, and my other classes say services are under `src/main/java/com/service` package. Do I still don't need `@ComponentScan`?

Comment: @SagarAhuja Man! That's not a best practices to create a spring boot application.